# How to hide column name in view. Using Visual Studio ASP.net and SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, listview, datalist

how to hide the name of the requested column when i show the data in an ASP.Net web application. problem is: i request some data from a sql table and show it on an asp.net webpage. now it shows the data but adds the column name in front (both in Listview and DataList). Like this: Columname: Data. How do i avoid the columnname been shown?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the columname simply delete or comment out the tag next to all  in html code.